# How to return least occuring values from an array in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of months, and I need to find the least occurring months/values in the list. I need to output the result to a single cell as a comma separated string. I've tried using the INDEX and MIN function, but this does not work as the MIN function only returns a single value. There are several months in the data that only occur once, and I need to see all of them.

Example:

```
Months
------
April
April
April
June
July
May
December
December
December
etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one has the dynamic formula in office 365:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER(A1:A10,FREQUENCY(MATCH(A1:A9,A:A,0),MATCH(A1:A9,A:A,0))=1))
```

Note that the first range is one row larger than the others.  Frequency creates an array with an extra row, so they need to match.

[image]